# How to request an html page using an ajax request in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to Rails to render the an `.html.erb` template through an ajax request under certain conditions. By default I keep getting back the `.js.erb` file when I send an ajax request.

I won't get into why I'm doing this, but I was wondering if there's either a way to specify when I'm sending the request through ajax that I'd like html content back rather than js, OR alternatively, if there's a way to refactor the following in Rails 3.1:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js do
    if params[:page].nil?
      render "home.html.erb"
    else
      render "home.js.erb"
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using jquery, you can set the dataType option, ie

```
$.ajax('some/page', {dataType: 'html'})
```

Or

```
$.get('some/page', function(){ //callback}, 'html')
```

Adding the format to the URL (ie. request '/some/page.html') should also work (regardless of how you make your request)